# Scaling SVGs with image pattern fills

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to fill an SVG shape using a pattern that contains an image. The SVGs are set to scale to fill their container but I'd like to stop the pattern scaling so the texture / resolution remains constant for all sizes. The SVG code is written directly into the HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>SVG Test</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #000;
        }

        svg {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<div style="width: 600px;">
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 390 390" style="enable-background:new 0 0 390 390;" xml:space="preserve" width="390" height="390">
        <g id="facebook" fill="url(#chalk-white)">
            <path class="st0" d="M195,0C87.3,0,0,87.3,0,195s87.3,195,195,195s195-87.3,195-195S302.7,0,195,0z M258.1,97.4l-27.5,0
                c-21.6,0-25.8,10.3-25.8,25.3v33.2h51.5l-6.7,52h-44.8v133.3h-53.7V207.8h-44.9v-52h44.9v-38.3c0-44.5,27.2-68.7,66.8-68.7
                c19,0,35.3,1.4,40.1,2V97.4z"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>

<svg height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="chalk-white" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="600" height="329">
            <image xlink:href="img/chalk-white.png" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="329" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

A link to a more complete version is here: http://whiterockbrewery.gg/dev/svgtest.html

As you'll see, the background image scales with the icon. Can I disable this scaling effect, keep the image (texture) the same size on all icons and have it tile if required?

I can half hack it by creating different pattern definitions and changing their width and height properties - half them and you effectively double the resolution of the text so can apply it to a bigger icon and keep some quality. However this solution is a bit cumbersome and doesn't work well for items that may need to scale dramatically with screen size changes or SVGs that may have been made at the wrong size in Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looked into it a bit more. Here's your problem. You're sizing your SVG as 100%/100% in CSS, and this is scaling the contents of your divs so that everything is being squeezed down. The SVG fragments don't know that they're being scaled up and down by their HTML container, so nothing that you do in SVG pattern attributes is going to affect anything.

When you do everything in pure SVG - http://codepen.io/mullany/pen/rtjeL - the patternUnits work just fine - with fixed texture sizes filling content of different sizes.

If you want to change this, you need to add a pattern-transform attribute inside your SVG to "reverse" the scaling effects of the HTML container scaling. Or you can do your scaling all in SVG.

Comment: I've not been able to get this to work successfully with a .png texture. This might be a limitation of web browsers, or perhaps I need to change some other properties too?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could link the svg through an img tag, thereby allowing for any type of resizing (also making it responsive). Im not sure though if the image pattern fill will still work. It seems to just go transparent when I try. Its worth a try though.

Comment: When I last tried this the SVG in an image didn't work. I've actually changed how it worked a bit since posting and use SVG filters to create some of the textures. I also use the InkScape command line to generate PNG fallback files.

Comment: Thats good too, I'm still facing the same problem though. I don't want to use a image for the whole thing because svg makes it easier to edit. Filters could be the way to go, if i can make a good texture! Thanks!